# Identify Facebook User ID

Tags: java, android, facebook, processing

Is it possible to identify the Facebook User ID of someone that has connected to the local network?

I want the Processing/Java application that runs in a computer in a local network to identify this ID when someone has connected to Facebook from the same network. I am not sure if this is possible and how it could be achieved.

Comment: So... you want to sniff cookies? *sniffle sniffle*

Comment: If this application is running on a separate computer from the one being used to connect to Facebook you won't even see the network traffic. You'd need to implement some form of proxy. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to be able to identify when a user has connected to the local network, but I want to make this as ubiquitous as possible. I know it should be rather complicated to perform this task, but I am considering options. Anything else that could be suggested for this? How about getting MAC address from devices connected to the network?

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt it's possible, although I'm willing to be proven wrong.

First of all, you would need to be able to silently monitor all relevant network traffic. The chances are that you physically can't do that unless you have access to the network infrastructure (e.g. re-routing cables, replacing a switch, or modifying a proxy). Simply being connected to the same network isn't usually enough.

Even if you overcome that challenge, you'll likely have to contend with encryption. More and more sites, including Facebook, are now supporting HTTPS throughout (not just at the login screen). That means the user ID may never be visible unless you can decrypt everything in real-time.